# How can I hide "Publish Major a Version" link on call out?

Tags: workflow, document-library, sharepoint-online, versioning

I'm looking for ways I can hide the "Publish a Major Version" link from a document library. The users must use a workflow in order to request approval rather than use this link.

Is there any way to hide this link?

Alternatively is it possible to link the starting of a workflow to this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now I feel really stupid.

I went and look at the workflow and saw that I could select "Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item." and of course that works perfectly.